# Past continuous 'have been'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english, past-tense

I tried to inform that the changes were reflected already in the system. How this could be communicated in a better way. Shall I use 'The changes have already been reflected in the system'? I am using have been here to say that it was done and the changes exist still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'The changes have already been reflected in the system' is grammatically correct and descriptive.  Other possibilities might be:

"The changes were made May 10, 2016, and are currently active."

"The changes have been active in the system since early 2016."

Comment: The changes have already been active in the system since yesterday evening. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that you use the word "already".  Examples:

Can you please make this update to the system?

*No, the change is already in the system.*

-or-

*The system was already updated.  It already shows that change.*

Did you make this update to the system?

*No, the change was already in the system.*

Was the change in the system for a period of time?

*Yes, the change has been here for a while.*